# What is LimitToList in JSF, RichFaces? Is it removed in RichFaces 4.x?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

What is `limitToList` in JSF, RichFaces? Is it removed in RichFaces 4.x? Are `limitToList` and `limitRender` the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`limitRender` in RichFaces 4.x is what `limitToList` is for RichFaces 3.x.

Except for `limitReder` is achieved through `render` attribute and `limitToList` is achieved through `reRender` attribute

Below is the explanation from RichFaces reference guide 3.x for `limitToList`.

> "limitToList" attribute allows to dismiss the behavior of the  "ajaxRendered" attribute. limitToList = "true" means to update only the area(s) that  mentioned in the "reRender" attribute explicitly. All output panels with ajaxRendered="true" is ignored. An example is placed below:

```
...
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{person.name}">
        <a4j:support event="onkeyup" reRender="test" limitToList="true"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <h:outputText value="#{person.name}" id="test"/>
</form>
...
```

Below is the explanation for `limitRender` from RichFaces development guide.

> RichFaces Ajax-enabled components and Ajax behaviors with limitRender="true" specified will not cause components with ajaxRendered="true" to re-render, and only those components listed in the render attribute will be updated. This essentially overrides the ajaxRendered attribute in other components.

References for RichFaces 3.x and 4.x can be found below.

- [RichFaces 4.x development guide](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Common_Ajax_attributes.html#sect-Component_Reference-Rendering-limitRender)
- [RichFaces 3.x reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html)
- [RichFaces Migration Guide. 3.3.x - 4.x Migration - Common components changes](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration-CommonComponentsChanges#core_attributes)

Comment: You might want to add a link to the [Richfaces migration guide](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration).

Comment: @mabi Not sure if OP was looking for the link you mentioned because his question was something else.

Comment: Just mentioning it for completeness and since it answers the question [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration-CommonComponentsChanges#core_attributes).